# How to share index Path with another Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I populate my collection view with achievement objects like so in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method:

```
let achievement = self.achievements[usableIndexPath.row]
```

Let's call this collection view A.

I'd like to pass the selected index from collection View A to collection View B.

I did that with the following:

I created a stored property in collection View B called "initialIndexPath". In the didSelectIndexPath method in collection View A, I set the "initialIndexPath" property to the index of the selected cell in collection view A.

selected cell's indexPath from Collection View A -> "InitialIndexPath" in Collection View B.

I do that like so:

In Collection View B:

```
/// 1st achievement to show in carousel
var initialIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
```

In collection View A:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

...
// - 1st achievement to show in carousel
achievementsDetailCollectionView.initialIndexPath = indexPath
```

In the cellForItemAtIndexPath method in Collection View B:

```
let achievement = self.achievements[initialIndexPath!.row]
```

The issue here is that every cell is the cell from the index of the selected cell of the collection view A.

I would like have the selected cell from collection View A to be the first cell viewed when loading collection View B

Comment: Does "collection View A" && "collection View B" in the same view controller?

Comment: No they are separate View Controllers

Comment: When selecting a cell from collection A, should it navigate you to the next viewController? if it is, are you using segues?

Comment: Yes it's navigating to the next view Controller, but I'm not using prepareForSegue

Comment: if you are prepareForSegue , store it in persistent storage and retrieve wherever you want or use singleton class variable to do that